# Inner join using LINQ on DataTables

Tags: c#, linq, inner-join

I have these 2 DataTables, `customerTableDT` and `customerAliasesTableDT`. They are both populated from a database like this:

```
customerTableDT = UtilityDataAndFunctions.PerformDBReadTransactionDataTableFormat(String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", TableNames.customers));

customerAliasesTableDT = UtilityDataAndFunctions.PerformDBReadTransactionDataTableFormat(String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", TableNames.customerAliases));
```

Now I'm trying to do an inner join on the two datatables like this:

```
var customerNames = from customers in customerTableDT.AsEnumerable()
                    join aliases in customerAliasesTableDT.AsEnumerable on customers.Field<int>("CustomerID") equals aliases.Field<int>("CustomerID")
                    where aliases.Field<string>("Alias").Contains(iString) select customers.Field<string>("Name")
```

But it gives me this error:

```
The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.
```

If I had to write in SQL about what I'm trying to do, its very simple:

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS C
INNER JOIN CustomerAliases ALIASES ON ALIASES.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
WHERE CA.Alias LIKE %STRING_HERE%
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed brackets after `AsEnumerable`, so it's treated as Method Group, not `IEnumerable<DataRow>`:

```
var customerNames = from customers in customerTableDT.AsEnumerable()
                    join aliases in customerAliasesTableDT.AsEnumerable() on customers.Field<int>("CustomerID") equals aliases.Field<int>("CustomerID")
                    where aliases.Field<string>("Alias").Contains(iString) select customers.Field<string>("Name")
```